# Updating OpenJDK in Redhat 7.6 - issue

Tags: java, linux

I need to update my version of OpenJDK on Redhat 7.6

My machine has the OpenJDK version "1.8.0_181" and I need to take it to  "1.8.0_201"

I downloaded java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.src.rpm, copied to my /tmp directory

I then executed this command :

```
rpm -i java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.src.rpm
```

Then I get a message of

```
warning : java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key IS 
c105b9de: NOKEY
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning : group mockbuild does not exist - using root
```

Then I type :

```
java -verison
```

And get the same original java version. Something is wrong.

Can someone tell me how to make sure this new version of java is running please?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the version you need not officially available so you can just update?

Answer (score 0):

You don't just install a src rpm package.

Step 1: Build it.

```
rpmbuild --rebuild java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.src.rpm
```

Step 2: Install the resulting binary rpm. The file name is probably slightly different.

```
rpm -i rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-2.el6_10.x86_64.rpm
```

Alternatively, download a prebuilt binary installation. [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/) (for example).

Comment: If the OP is going to build from sources, it would be a good idea to create the missing `mockbuild` user and group by hand, then uninstall / reinstall the RPM.  But, like you, I'm not convinced that building from a source RPM is necessary ...